# Looking to pull the first time every individual users ID shows in a string column (Oracle SQL Developer)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

**Using: Oracle SQL Developer (Version 21.4.2.018)**
--but the system is updated with LextEdit (which I do not use)

**Description**

First off, I am very new to SQL. I am trying to create a table that shows when a end user is created in our system and when they are deleted from our system. The first time their ID appears to be added to a 'role', in column 3, is when they were added to the system. When it says "removed from all roles" is when they were deleted. I am pulling from 2 different tables. One is our audit that only goes back about 10 days and the other is the archive that goes back to the beginning of time (Hello World).

**Problem**

I am trying to find the best way to find the first time a users ID shows in column 3 (Upd_Des) with the wording "Added usr_id = *USERS ID* to role_id *blah*". There are multiple times the users ID shows throughout the tables. I do not want to be specific with the user ID names because there will be 100's of different ID's in column 3. I can not figure out what function I need to achieve this. Also, I am not sure if I am even writing this correctly, but it does seem to be pulling all the information I need to get it going.
Info:
Column 1, Upd_Date, is the date the account was updated
Column 2, Usr, is the person who made the change to the account (system admin)
Column 3, Upd_Des, is the description of the change to the end users account

**What I have so far**

```
Select Upd_Date, Usr, Upd_Des
From (
SELECT auddte Upd_Date, usr_id Usr, exec_cmd Upd_Des
FROM arc_sys_audit
WHERE aud_typ = 'I'
AND appl_id <> 'LEXTEDIT'
AND appl_id <> 'srvcmdopr'
AND appl_id <> 'srvcmdmnt'
AND exec_cmd LIKE ('%from all roles%')
AND auddte >= sysdate -365
UNION all 
SELECT auddte Upd_Date, usr_id Usr, exec_cmd Upd_Des
FROM arc_sys_audit
WHERE aud_typ = 'I'
AND appl_id <> 'LEXTEDIT'
AND appl_id <> 'srvcmdopr'
AND appl_id <> 'srvcmdmnt'
AND exec_cmd LIKE ('%Added usr_id = % to role_id%')
AND auddte >= sysdate -365
union all
SELECT auddte Upd_Date, usr_id Usr, exec_cmd Upd_Des
FROM sys_audit
WHERE aud_typ = 'I'
AND appl_id <> 'LEXTEDIT'
AND appl_id <> 'srvcmdopr'
AND appl_id <> 'srvcmdmnt'
AND exec_cmd LIKE ('%from all roles%')
AND auddte >= sysdate -365
UNION all 
SELECT auddte Upd_Date, usr_id Usr, exec_cmd Upd_Des
FROM sys_audit
WHERE aud_typ = 'I'
AND appl_id <> 'LEXTEDIT'
AND appl_id <> 'srvcmdopr'
AND appl_id <> 'srvcmdmnt'
AND exec_cmd LIKE ('%Added usr_id = % to role_id%')
AND auddte >= sysdate -365)
order by Upd_Date desc
```

**Results** --There are 1000's of rows, but for this example I'll just give you 20.

```
|Upd_Date     |Usr          |Upd_Des
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|17-APR-23  |SYSADMIN1  |Added usr_id = EMPLOYEE1 to role_id = JNJ Quality
|17-APR-23  |SYSADMIN1  |Added usr_id = EMPLOYEE1 to role_id = REPORT_USER
|12-APR-23  |SYSADMIN2  |Added usr_id = EMPLOYEE2 to role_id = Warehouse Operator
|10-APR-23  |SYSADMIN1  |Removed user_id = EMPLOYEE3 from all roles
|07-APR-23  |SYSADMIN3  |Added usr_id = EMPLOYEE4 to role_id = RECEIVING
|07-APR-23  |SYSADMIN3  |Added usr_id = EMPLOYEE4 to role_id = REPORT_ADMIN
|07-APR-23  |SYSADMIN3  |Added usr_id = EMPLOYEE4 to role_id = LITEWM
|07-APR-23  |SYSADMIN3  |Added usr_id = EMPLOYEE4 to role_id = GENERAL_MANAGER
|07-APR-23  |SYSADMIN3  |Added usr_id = EMPLOYEE4 to role_id = QUALITY_MANAGER
|07-APR-23  |SYSADMIN3  |Added usr_id = EMPLOYEE4 to role_id = OPS_SUPERVISOR
|07-APR-23  |SYSADMIN3  |Added usr_id = EMPLOYEE4 to role_id = ORDER
|07-APR-23  |SYSADMIN3  |Added usr_id = EMPLOYEE4 to role_id = WORKFLOW
|07-APR-23  |SYSADMIN3  |Added usr_id = EMPLOYEE4 to role_id = WM_USER
|07-APR-23  |SYSADMIN3  |Added usr_id = EMPLOYEE4 to role_id = QUALITY_ASSOCIATE
|07-APR-23  |SYSADMIN3  |Added usr_id = EMPLOYEE4 to role_id = OPERATIONS_MANAGER
|07-APR-23  |SYSADMIN3  |Added usr_id = EMPLOYEE4 to role_id = WORKMANAGER
|07-APR-23  |SYSADMIN3  |Added usr_id = EMPLOYEE4 to role_id = SHIPPING_MANAGER
|07-APR-23  |SYSADMIN3  |Added usr_id = EMPLOYEE4 to role_id = CSRV
```

**What I would like this to show**

```
|Upd_Date     |Usr          |Upd_Des
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|17-APR-23  |SYSADMIN1  |Added usr_id = EMPLOYEE1 to role_id = REPORT_USER
|12-APR-23  |SYSADMIN2  |Added usr_id = EMPLOYEE2 to role_id = Warehouse Operator
|10-APR-23  |SYSADMIN1  |Removed user_id = EMPLOYEE3 from all roles
|07-APR-23  |SYSADMIN3  |Added usr_id = EMPLOYEE4 to role_id = CSRV
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look into the ROW_NUMBER windowing function using PARTITION BY and ORDER BY clauses in the windowing to create a ranking, then in an outer parent query block select only the top result ( = 1). I'm sure someone will write it for you in a few minutes, but you'd be better off reading up on ROW_NUMBER and figuring it out yourself.

Comment: SQL Developer is an IDE used to talk to databases; it is **NOT** a database and knowing the version of SQL Developer is not helpful. You need to tell us the version of the database you are connecting to.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the `usr_id` from the string using string functions and then use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY usr_id ORDER BY upd_dat)` to give the rows an index  that increments for each `usr_id` in date order and then filter to find the rows indexed first:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT q.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(upd_des, '=\s*(.*?)\s(to|from)', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
           ORDER BY upd_dat
         ) AS rn
  FROM   (
    <insert your query here>
  ) q
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```